# Google Mobile Frieldy ignores mobile version even it Vary: User-Agent is set

Tags: google, google-search-console, mobile, google-insights

We have our website in two versions - desktop and mobile. Checking on multiple devices, Android, iOS and various browsers mobile device simulations, mobile site is properly loaded.
Despite of this fact Google Mobile Friendly Test sees our website only as desktop version. Ignores `Vary: User-Agent` tag. Test fails.

Interesting thing is that another Google test [Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) sees the same website as mobile (test passess).

Is there any trick/gotcha to make test pass on both tools?

Comment: what happens if you do Fetch as Google on the mobile smartphone version of a  page on your site?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is check the server access logs after testing your website with each tool to see what identification google uses. Search the logs for googlebot or IP addresses that match google. Also, search the logs for part of the URL of the page you requested for each test to help you track google down.

Once you done that, you need to modify your mobile detection routine accordingly to redirect the google bots to the correct version of your website.